# How to bind a VNC port with a KVM?

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, vnc

How can I bind a VNC port with a specific virtual machine (KVM) so after a reboot of the host server all ports would remain the same? Right now the numeration of ports is based on the order of switching on the VMs.
So I want, for example, the port 5900 to be bind with VM1 and 5901 - with VM2

Comment: Can't you put the port in the XML file?

Answer (score 2):

```
 <graphics type='vnc' port='5900' autoport='no' listen='0.0.0.0'>
  <listen type='address' address='0.0.0.0'/>
</graphics>
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much this worked for me